# PHP script on value attribute

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to directly use php scripts at the html attributes. I'm using the following code to show some text on the text box.

```
<input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo "name";?>"/><br/>
```

But, it shows `<?php echo` on the text box. I've seen at [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_form_complete.asp) and changed it to `"<?php echo $name;?>"`. Now it shows `<?php echo $name;?>` on the text box.

I'm confused. How to use `php` to show some text on the value attribute of input type?

Comment: Is the extension of your file .php?. Do you have a php interpreter installed?

Comment: If you're seeing `<?php` in your browser, it's because you're server isn't actually running your scripts through PHP.

Comment: the extension is html

Comment: you should change the quotes in your code to `<input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo 'name';?>"/><br/>` and make sure the extension of the file is `.php` and not `.html`

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that your file is `php` not the `html` file.If your file extension is `.html` then change it to `.php` and try it.And also try to change like :

```
<input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo 'name';?>"/><br/>
```

You cont use double quotes in the double quotes.Change them to `single quotes`.

**Note :**  Also you can use `tpl`/`phtml` files also but with extension `.tpl`/`.phtml`.

Comment: Please tell me the reason to down..??

Comment: I have to guess: the file extension and such the right server module to handle the script surely are the reason for the problem. But why mention the quotes? it doesn't matter which quotes are outside of the php context, the PHP interpreter only sees `echo "name";` - and that is as valid as `echo 'name'; `

Comment: Ok try with value='<?php echo 'name';?>' and tell me the output

Comment: `value='name'` - what did you expect? the PHP interpreter still ignores anything outside the `<?php` (`<?=`, ..) tags ;)

Answer (score 0):

you should use

```
<input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo 'name';?>"/>
```

use single contention not double contention in php echo

for more tutorial visit 
http://w3webtutorial.blogspot.com/

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$name="name";
?>
<input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $name;?>" placeholder="haiiii"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can't able to write php code in html page, but you can write html in php page.